# Reponse Data with Selenium driver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

The code below currently opens page and logins into site. URL is a private company link I can not post.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Edge()
url = 'SomeURL'

def login(url):
    driver.get(url)
    print('1')
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=text]").send_keys("Username")
    print('2')
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=password]").send_keys("password")
    print('3')
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type=submit]").click()
    print('4') #####Here is where I am having issues#####
    json = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("pre")
    print(json)
    return(json)

data = login(url)
```

The function is missing a critical part of what I need. Once I have logged in I need to return the text inside pre html tag form the new page.

My print statement returns this

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="79adcfff4b079a895939502f55ce2fc9", element="29fb8a33-a986-40cb-9b1b-2041096f6240")>
```

How do I return the text inside pre tag once I have logged into site that what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After print 4 these are the commands to run in order to get page source from new login in page and return the html back to caller.

```
newURI = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to.window(newURI)
time.sleep(3)
print('5')
pageSource = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
print('6')
return(pageSource)
```